# Detecting changed attributes when form save is complete

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Ultimately what I'm looking for is an `onSaveComplete` event.

The problem is that we have plugins that modify entity data when it is saved. For most attributes this is fine, because the data is updated on the form after the save completes. Client scripts are problematic though because (as far as I can tell) there are no events to indicate that a value was updated by a plugin when the entity was saved.

The best solution I have come up with is to hook into the `onSave` event, prevent the default save action, and use `data.save()` instead:

```js
function onSave(context) {
    var args = context.getEventArgs();
    args.preventDefault();

    Xrm.Page.data.save().then(function() {
        //check for changed attributes here
    });
}
```

(Actual code is a bit more complicated to prevent recursion, etc. but you get the idea)

Ultimately this approach ends up being quite messy, and the more forms I apply it to, the more it feels like a real hack. So my question is - is there a better, more standard way to approach this?

Comment: The field attributes should reflect any changes your plugins make - what exactly do you need to do in your _onSaveComplete_ method?

Comment: @JasonFaulkner Yeah the attributes do reflect the changes, that part is fine. But in response to those changes that were made in the plugin I need to apply some additional changes in the client script. So effectively what I want is an event that tells me when certain attributes have been changed by a plugin. And if not specific attribute changed events, at least a generic save complete event that I don't have to hack in.

What confuses me the most is that, with the new CRM 2013 async save model, how there can be no onSaveComplete type event out of the box.

Comment: I believe your 'hack' method is the only supported way to accomplish what you are looking to do.

Comment: The lifecycle of the save event makes this difficult, if not impossible.  But what you have there already is a very clever solution to this problem.  
Client side code can't see what happens in a plugin, because the plugins run server-side, simple as that.  You have to compare the attributes before/after a save event, which is exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @dkr88 thanks for posting, was wondering how you go about checking of an attribute has changed. Is there some sort of HasChanged property?

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished something similar to a post-save JS event through a different kind of "hack".

Here's how it works:

- Put `ModifiedOn` field on the form
- Subscribe to `ModifiedOn`'s `OnChange` event

The event you attach to the `OnChange` will fire every time the form is saved (because when data changes so does `ModifiedOn`).

It's very likely that `ModifiedOn` should be made read-only on the form, to avoid clashing scripts.

Comment: ModifiedOn is readonly still when i open a record it changes ModifiedOn date.